# Responsive - align icon and text to center of the menu item

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I have multiple menu items that are displayed horizontally. In each menu item I have a span icon (data-icon) and a text. They are centered with text-align:center. Some menu item texts are long. Everything is OK until I get into smaller screens.

The problem is that when the text breaks to the next line it gets centered inside the menu item container and goes under the icon.

Is there a way to prevent and center item text by itself but also leave Icon and Text centered inside the menu container ?

```css
.mycontainer {
  width: 50%;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.big-icon {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.small-text {
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="mycontainer">
    <span class="big-icon">Big Icon</span>
    <span class="small-text">This is very very very very very very very very very long text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="mycontainer" style="background: yellow;">
    <span class="big-icon">Big Icon</span>
    <span class="small-text">This is short text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use **[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)**

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.mycontainer {
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.big-icon {
  font-size: 40px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.small-text {
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 1 40%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="menu">
  <div class="mycontainer">
    <span class="fa fa-address-book-o fa-4x"></span>
    <span class="small-text">This is very very very very veryveryveryveryverylongtext</span>
  </div>
  <div class="mycontainer" style="background: yellow;">
    <span class="fa fa-address-book-o fa-4x"></span>
    <span class="small-text">This is short text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this but this did not center Icon and text together inside the container

Comment: @user3410843 have you tried the above css....as Its working in the snippet well....what is the issue you are facing

Comment: @user3410843 maybe you share your exact HTML markup

Comment: if the flex-basis:content was supported my issues would have been solved with flexbox. I am looking for a workaround to flex-basis:content.

Comment: @user3410843 flex-basis:content.....?...sorry but its not clear what you are saying..

Comment: Your solution does not center the icon and the text together inside the yellow box.

Comment: @user3410843 If you want them horizontally center use `justify-content:center` to the parent....Check updated answer....

Comment: @user3410843 have you checked the updated answer...it will fix your alignment issue

Comment: Sorry for the delay but it does not work properly with font icons
<span class="" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe01d;"></span>
When long text with long word is wrapped into the next line it will not shrink its box width so the text gets far from the icon. Attached the example

Comment: @user3410843 You have to use `flex:0 1 40%` to the `small-text` class...adjust `40%` according to your requirement....See Updated answer...

Answer (score 0):

You could use css grids to make this a lot easier.

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
}
p {
  grid-column: 3/5;
}
h1 {
  grid-column: 1/3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu {
  display: grid
}

.mycontainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px; // adds padding to columns
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; //defines two columns (1/2 each)
  align-items: center; //Centers children vertically
  justify-items: center; //Centers children horizontally
  background: green
}

.big-icon {
  font-size: 40px
}

.small-text {
  font-size: 12px
}
```

Here is JSFiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afdgLjz8/)

More here: [Alligator io aligment tutorial](https://alligator.io/css/align-justify/)